# Take max date row from duplicates and remove duplicates in the list using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a below linq query and getting data like below example want to remove duplications

```
List<EmployeeSalary> lstEmployeeSalary = 
   new EmployeeSalaryFactory().GetRelatedObjects(inValue, ddlPayDate, payRollType, payrollSearch)
                              .Select(m => (EmployeeSalary)m)
                              .ToList();
```

For ex.:

```
Id        Name        EmpCode       Salary      DateOfSalary
-------------------------------------------------------------
1         Item1       IT00001        $100         5/26/2021 
2         Item2       IT00002        $200         4/26/2021 
3         Item3       IT00003        $150         5/26/2021 
1         Item1       IT00001        $100         4/26/2021 
3         Item3       IT00003        $150         4/26/2021
```

Output

```
Id        Name        EmpCode       Salary      DateOfSalary
-------------------------------------------------------------
1         Item1       IT00001        $100         5/26/2021 
2         Item2       IT00002        $200         4/26/2021 
3         Item3       IT00003        $150         5/26/2021
```

Comment: Group by the Id, Max the date, First the others. What isn't clear to me is how the posted code relates to the posted table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suppose that `new EmployeeSalaryFactory().GetRelatedObjects(...)` returns list of `EmployeeSalary` objects:

```cs
List<EmployeeSalary> lstEmployeeSalary = 
    new EmployeeSalaryFactory().GetRelatedObjects(...)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateOfSalary).First());
```

**Test**

```cs
IList<EmployeeSalary> clients = new List<EmployeeSalary>()
{
     new EmployeeSalary { Id=1, Name = "Item1", EmpCode="IT00001", Salary=100, DateOfSalary= new DateTime(2021,5,26)},
     new EmployeeSalary { Id=2, Name = "Item2", EmpCode="IT00002", Salary=200, DateOfSalary= new DateTime(2021,4,26)},
     new EmployeeSalary { Id=3, Name = "Item3", EmpCode="IT00003", Salary=150, DateOfSalary= new DateTime(2021,5,26)},
     new EmployeeSalary { Id=1, Name = "Item1", EmpCode="IT00001", Salary=100, DateOfSalary= new DateTime(2021,4,26)},
     new EmployeeSalary { Id=3, Name = "Item3", EmpCode="IT00003", Salary=150, DateOfSalary= new DateTime(2021,4,26)},
}

    var res = clients.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.EmpCode, x.Salary })
                     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateOfSalary).First());

    foreach (var it in res.ToList())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(it.Id + ", " + it.Name + ", " + it.EmpCode + ", " + it.Salary + ", " + it.DateOfSalary); 
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1, Item1, IT00001, 100, 5/26/2021 00:00:00
2, Item2, IT00002, 200, 4/26/2021 00:00:00
3, Item3, IT00003, 150, 5/26/2021 00:00:00
```

Comment: i tried like this it is not working:  lstEmployeeSalary .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.EmpCode,x.Salary }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateOfSalary).First()).ToList(); .@Jackdaw

Comment: @MazharKhan: I have added test to the answer. Show your input-output. What exactly does **NOT WORKING**?

Comment: sorry your code working fine i have assign wrongly. @Jackdaw

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do the `ToList()` inside your procedures, unless you will be using the fact that the result is a `List<EmployeeSalary>`.
If you only intend to return the fetched data to your caller, consider to return `IEnumerable<EmployeeSalary>` and let the caller do the ToList.

The reason for this, is that if you caller doesn't want to use all fetched data, it would be a waste of processing power to materialize it all:

Suppose you have the following methods to get the EmployeeSalaries:

```
private EmployeeSalaryFactory {get;} = new EmployeeSalaryFactory();

IEnumerable<EmployeeSalary> GetEmployeeSalaries() 
{
    return this.EmployeeSalaryFactory
        .GetRelatedObjects(inValue, ddlPayDate, payRollType, payrollSearch)
        .Select(m => (EmployeeSalary)m);
}
```

It might be that inValue, ddlPayDate, etc are parameters of this method, but that's outside the question.

Now let's use this method:

```
EmployeeSalary GetSalary(int employeeId)
{
    return this.GetEmployeeSalaries()
        .Where(salary => salary.EmployeeId == employeeId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If GetEmployeeSalaries would have returned a `List<EmployeeSalary>` then all salaries would have been materialized, while the caller might only needed a few.

### Back to your question

> I want to remove duplications

The answer depends on what you would call a *duplicate*: When are two EmployeeSalaries equal? Is that if all properties have equal value, or are two salaries equal if they have the same Id (but possibly different Salary).

I assume the first: all values should be checked for equality

#### The quick solution

If you only need to do this for this usage only, if you don't need to massively unit test it, don't need to prepare for future changes, don't want to be able to reuse the code for similar problems, consider to use [Queryable.Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Distinct__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__) before your Select.

The result of

Of course, if the data is in your local process (not in a database), you can use the IEnumerable equivalent.

```
var uniqueSalaries = this.EmployeeSalaryFactory
        .GetRelatedObjects(inValue, ddlPayDate, payRollType, payrollSearch)
        .Select(salary => new
        {
            // Select all properties that you need to make a Salary:
            Id = salary.Id,
            Name = salary.EmpCode,
            Salary = salary.Salary,
            Date = salary.DateOfSalary,
        })
        .Distinct()
```

Before the Distinct, the selected objects are of anonymous type. They have a default equality comparer that compares by value, not by reference. So two objects of this anonymous type that have equal value for every property are considered to be equal. Distinct will remove duplicates.

If you really need that the result is `IEnumerable<EmployeeSalary>`, you'll need a second select:

```
.Select(uniqueSalary => new EmployeeSalary
{
    Id = uniqueSalary.Id,
    Name = uniqueSalary.Name,
    ...
});
```

### Proper solution

If the input data is in your local process (= it is IEnumerable), you have more LINQ methods at your disposal, like the [overload of Enumerable.Distinct that has a parameter EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__).

In that case, my advice would be to create an Equality comparer for EmployeeSalaries. This will have the advantage that you can reuse the equality comparer for other EmployeeSalary problems. The code will look easier to read. You are prepared for future changes: if you add or remove a property from your definition of equality, for instance if you only need to check the Id, there is only one place that you have to change. You can unit test the comparer: didn't you forget some properties?

```
private EmployeeSalaryFactory {get;} = new EmployeeSalaryFactory();
private IEqualityComparer<EmployeeSalary> SalaryComparer {get} = ...;

private IEnumerable<EmployeeSalary> GetEmployeeSalaries() { ... see above }
```

To get the unique salaries:

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeSalary> uniqueSalaries = this.GetEmployeeSalaries()
    .Distinct(this.SalaryComparer);
```

Did you notice, that because I reuse a lot of code, the specific problem of unique salaries is quite easy to understand.

I cheated a little, I moved the problem to the equality comparer.

### IEquality

Creating a reusable equality comparer is fairly straightforward. The advantage is that you can reuse it in all cases where you need to compare EmployeeSalaries. If in future your definition of equality changes, there is only one place that you need to change. Finally: only one place where you need to unit test whether you implemented the proper definition of equality.

```
public class EmployeeSalaryComparer : EqualityComparer<EmployeeSalary>()
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<EmployeeSalary> ByValue {get} = new EmployeeSalaryComparer;

    public override bool Equals (EmployeeSalary x, EmployeeSalary y) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode (EmployeeSalary x) {...}
}
```

Usage would be:

```
IEqualityComparer<EmployeeSalary> salaryComparer = EmployeeSalaryComparer.ByValue;

EmployeeSalary employee1 = ...
EmployeeSalary employee2 = ...

bool equal = salaryComparer.Equals(employee1, employee2);
```

### Implement equality

```
public override bool Equals (EmployeeSalary x, EmployeeSalary y)
{
```

Almost all equality comparers start with the following lines:

```
    if (x == null) return y == null;              // true if both null
    if (y == null) return false;                  // because x not null
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) return true; // same object 
    if (x.GetType() != y.GetType() return false;
```

After this, the real comparing for equality starts. The implementation depends on what you call equality. You might say: same Id is equal EmployeeSalary. Our aproach is to check all fields, for instance to see if we need to update the database, because some values are changed:

```
    return x.Id == y.Id
        && x.Name == y.Name
        && x.EmpCode == y.EmpCode
        && x.Salary == y.Salary
        && x.DateOfSalary == y.DateOfSalary;
}
```

Are in your definition the names: "John Doe" and "john doe" equal? And when are EmpCodes equal?

If you think they are not default, or might change in future, consider to add properties to the EmployeeSalaryComparer:

```
private static IEqualityComparer<string> NameComparer {get} = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
private static IEqualityComparer<string> EmpCodeComparer {get} = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
...
```

The check for equality will end like:

```
return IdComparer.Equals(x.Id, y.Id)
    && NameComparer.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)
    && EmpCodeComparer.Equals(x.EmpCode, y.EmpCode)
    && SalaryComparer.Equals(x.Salary, y.Salary)
    && DateComparer.Equals(x.DateOfSalary, y.DateOfSalary);
```

If company policy about names in future changes, then all you have to do is select a different name comparer. And if EmpCode "Boss" is the same as EmpCode "boss": only one place to change the code.

Of course, after spec changes you need to change your unit tests, so they will tell you automatically where you forgot to change the proper equality comparers.

### GetHashCode

GetHashCode is used to quickly check for inequality. Keywords: quickly, and inequality. If two Hash codes are different, we know that the object are not equal. It is not the other way round: if two hash codes are equal, we don't know whether the objects are equal.

The hash code is meant to quickly throw away most unequal objects. For instance, in a Distinct method, it would be nice if you could quickly throw away 99% of the objects, so you only have to thoroughly check 1% of the objects for equality.

With EmployeeSalaries we know that if the Id is different, than the Salaries are not equal. It will seldom be that two EmployeeSalaries will have the same Id, but different EmpCode. So by checking the Id only, we throw away most unequal EmployeeSalaries.

How about this:

```
public override int GetHashCode (EmployeeSalary x)
{
    if (x == null) return 9875578;   // just a number for null salaries

    return x.Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

### Conclusion

- We've discussed why it is better to return IEnumerable instead of ToList.
- We've talked about methods to make your code reusable, easier to read, maintainable, easier to unit test
- We've talked about equality comparers
- We've used Distinct to solver you problem

Comment: i tried like this it is not working: lstEmployeeSalary .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.EmpCode,x.Salary }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateOfSalary).First()).ToList(); .@Harald Coppoolse

Comment: Your OrderBy tries to Order the result of GroupBy, which is a sequence of `IGrouping<...>`. These IGroupings don't have a property `DateOfSalary`. Hence you can't OrderBy this property. Note that the result of GroupBy is a collection of Groups. Every Group has the Key which is the `new {...}`. Every group is a sequence of EmployeeSalaries. If you want to Order by one of the properties of the Key, use `Select(group => group.Name)`. If you want to order the elements of the Group, use the overload of GroupBy with parameter resultSelector.